# How to redirect different users to view different pages in laravel version 6.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

I need to redirect users to different url according to their their login details.

**For Example**

- If the user id of 1 logs in he should be redirected. "/home"
- If the user id of 2 logs in he should be redirected. "/contact"
- And when they are logged out they should be redirected to the index page. "/"
- And if they tries to paste the "/contact" url when they are logged out it should redirect them to "login" url

Answer (score 3):

For LogedIn User in your controller

```
if(auth()->user()->id ==1){
    return redirect("/home");
}elseif(auth()->user()->id ==2){
    return redirect("/contact");
}else{
    return redirect("/index");
}
```

And if they tries to paste the "/contact" url when they are logged out it should redirect them to "login" url

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/contact', 'Controller@method')->middleware('auth:user');
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which version of Laravel you are using, all i can suggest is looking at the documentation on Authentication [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating) for your version.

Here is basic example from laravel 7.x

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php**

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // Add your logic here (switch statement)

    return response([
        //
    ]);
}
```

Also look at the documentation on protecting routes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#protecting-routes)

**app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php**

```
/**
 * Get the path the user should be redirected to.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return string
 */
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    // Add your logic here (switch statement)

    return route('login');
}
```

Comment: its laravel version 6.2

Comment: please may get an example of logic to be written in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php ?

Comment: I am here to help you to help yourself, not to write the code for you. Can you post what you have tried so far in your question and then if you get stuck, let me know :)